# Dockerfile - pip3 install from private github repo using personal token

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am creating a docker image for my python code.
To install dependencies and requirements, I have

```
pip3 install git+https://$GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/<PATH_TO_REPO>@dev --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall
```

in the Dockerfile. when I run docker build command, I get below error

```
Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'https://****@github.com/<PATH_TO_REPO>.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-cxx5g22f
  fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I am running docker build using GitHub action and passing the `GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` in build argument.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If it is a "Personal Access Token" (PAT) and not an OAuth-Token, you have to specify your user name e.g.

```
pip3 install git+https://username:$GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/<PATH_TO_REPO>@dev --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall
```

Replace `username` with your GitHub username the PAT belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I can try this but the question is why the `pip3 install git+https://$GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/<PATH_TO_REPO>@dev --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall` is not working in docker environment. it works file when I deploy the code in a VM.

Comment: As pip uses git under the hood for this, if could be the case that git uses some already set credentials from your vm and ignores the PAT. But this depends on your set up.

Comment: This worked -> `pip3 install git+https://oauth2:$GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/<PATH_TO_REPO>@dev --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

This worked -> `pip3 install git+https://oauth2:$GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/<PATH_TO_REPO>@dev --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall`